# How can I get (and format) the current date on my WordPress blog site home page?

Tags: php, wordpress, timestamp

Today is Friday, December 14, 2018. I would like to add the current date to my WordPress blog headline. I've tried these three methods in my front page php template:

Method 1:

```php
<?php the_time('l, F j, Y') ?>
```

That yields: Thursday, December 13, 2018

Method 2:

```php
<?php echo date ('Y/m/d');?>
```

That yields: 2018/12/15

Method 3 (in-line javascript):

```php
<p><script> document.write(new Date().toLocaleDateString()); </script></p>
```

That yields: 12/14/2018

I tried putting all three in consecutive paragraphs on my home page. Only method 3 gives the correct date. It would take some more work to format it as desired (as in Method 1).

Why do the three methods all return different dates?

Note that my php.ini file on my web host's server has my correct time zone, and the General Settings on my WordPress site has my correct time zone.

Comment: Have you tried [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)?

Comment: My web search on this issue yielded some pages that indicated that such an approach is deprecated. Also, to what would I set it? Method 1 above yields a date in the past; method 2 yields a date in the future. It seems unlikely that a time zone setting would fix both of those.

Comment: Why would it be deprecated? The manual clearly shows `(PHP 5 >= 5.1.0, PHP 7)` with no deprecation notice. What were those pages you speak of?

Comment: Just set the timezone to the one that corresponds. I don't know what else to say here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<?php echo get_the_date(); ?>`.
Setup your Timezone in your dashboard, on Settings > General

Comment: Today is Saturday, December 15, 2018. The suggested code yields "Thursday, December 13, 2018", which is the same incorrect value as Method 1 in the post. This date is, coincidentally, the date of my most recent post. Is there some connection?